# SQL Table design (select * from table where ( field = search1, and field = search2)

Tags: sql, database-design

PatientDX

```
Name   Disease
Aa      HIV
Aba     DM
Bb      HT
Bb      DM
Aa      HT
```

I want to get patient names who have both HIV, DM or all diseases or something like that. I want to make analysis by disease checkboxes in UI. How can I do it? Is my table design bad? Could you suggest me a better way to achieve that? Disease names can be as many as 100. So, I want to make it easy to find out patients who have particular 3 diseases, 4 or 5 and so on. Thank you.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear ("or something like that").  Provide sample data, desired results. It is helpful to include any queries that you have tried.  And tag your question with the database you are actually using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema is good.

Here is an example of how to query for patients having all 3 specific diseases:

```
select Name
from PatientDX
where Disease in ('HIV', 'DM', 'HT')
group by Name
having count(distinct Disease) = 3
```

A few important things to note here:

- We use `distinct` in the `having` clause to make sure that if only `'HIV'` was passed in 3 times (I'm assuming you will be using parameterized queries) we wouldn't get a result back.
- The value you are comparing `count` to (in this case, 3) must match the number of values in the `in` clause.
- The list of values in the `IN` clause must be unique before you count them.

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping by user and then using having clause in your query. So to find a patient who has more than one disease you could query like:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM PatientDX
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Disease) > 1
```

If you wish to know patient who has all the diseases then you could do something like:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM PatientDX
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Disease) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Disease)
                                  FROM PatientDX)-- although you could maintain disease in another table.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :D